# Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field? Choices are: active, admin, email, full_name, id, etc

Tags: python, django, django-models

After switching into django custom user model reset password is not working and showing these errors....

> Internal Server Error: /password-reset/ Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 124, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
>   line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
>   line 45, in _wrapper
>       return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
>   line 142, in _wrapped_view
>       response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
>   line 1263, in add_q
>       clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
>   line 1287, in _add_q
>       split_subq=split_subq,
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
>   line 1164, in build_filter
>       lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
>   line 1028, in solve_lookup_type
>       _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
>
> File
>   "/home/nasrullah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
>
> line 1389, in names_to_path
>       "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available))) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active'
>
> into field. Choices are: active, admin, email, full_name, id, image,
>
> last_login, logentry, password, post, staff, timestamp [01/Feb/2020
>
> 13:03:45] "POST /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 149279

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    #path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name= 'users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('login/',user_views.login_page, name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/',
             auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
             auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
             auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
             auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),

]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
     AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, full_name, password, is_active=True,is_staff=False,is_admin=False):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a password')

        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a full name')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.active = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, full_name, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email    = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name='email address',
            max_length=255,
            unique=True,
        )
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics/')
    active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.full_name:
            return self.full_name
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email




    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return self.is_admin

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active



class GuestEmail(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Implementing a custom user model is not a trivial thing in Django, except when starting a new project, and you haven't stated whether you followed the documentation, nor whether this is a change in an existing project under development.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to strip the project down by removing everything which is not essentially neede to demonstrate the problem. You might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere (in code you haven't included, `views.py` most likely) you are trying to filter or query the `User` model over the field `is_active`. However that field doesn't exist on the model, it's a `property` of the model, and so can't be resolved.

Read the error message and it tells you exactly this:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field.
Choices are: active, admin, email, full_name, id, image, last_login, logentry, password, post, staff, timestamp
```

Those are the fields on `User` and consequently those are the fields available for querying over that model.

So, make sure the in arguments being passed to the query (wherever that is happening) uses `active` instead of `is_active` and it should succeed.